# 4 columns to 2 columns with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a 4 columns fluid-layout:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">A</div>
        <div class="span3">B</div>
        <div class="span3">C</div>
        <div class="span3">D</div>
    </div>
</div>

[  A  ][  B  ][  C  ][  D  ]
```

For mobile devices, bootstrap renders the columns one under another, which works fine:

```
[            A             ]
[            B             ]
[            C             ]
[            D             ]
```

But for tablets, I'd like to have 2 columns of 2:

```
[      A     ][      B     ]
[      C     ][      D     ]
```

Is it possible achieve this behavior natively with bootstrap?

Comment: There is no such functionality available natively, afaik.

Comment: Yeah, not natively. I have done it myself though by overriding some of Bootstrap's CSS. Would you be interested in seeing it?

Comment: Ok that's what I thought :( And yes, I'm curious to see how you did it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that Zurb Foundation (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/grid.php#threeBlockEx) offers this fonctionality, but I want to continue with Twitter Bootstrap. So I've managed to add a custom rule, based on the technique that Foundation uses :

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    .row-fluid > [class*=span]:nth-child(2n+1) {
      clear: both;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Emilie's answer you also need to reset the widths of the columns,

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    .row-fluid > [class*=span]:nth-child(2n+1) {
        clear: both;
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .row-fluid .span3 {
        width: 48.61878453038674%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! But don't do the same mistake as I did - forget to include the stylesheet AFTER the bootstrap css - and save yourself some hours :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll just need to override the CSS for the spans in the `@media` query corresponding to tablets.

So you can try something like this:

```
// Tablets & small desktops only
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  [class*=span] {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Of course, adjustments may need to be made. Because of padding and margins, the width may not actually be 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I tried both of those rules in my CSS and neither of them worked for me. It is a shame that this is missing in BS 2.0. I hope they add it in BS 3.0!

Thanks,

JK