# Responsive columns for tablets, desktops and phones. Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been having a look at "[4 columns to 2 columns with Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988062/4-columns-to-2-columns-with-twitter-bootstrap)"; but I have not gotten it to work ...

Could you give me more detailed instructions, please?

I'm using bootstrap 3.0.

Os I'll be very grateful! I have spent many days trying to do it without success...

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"> //content  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"> //content  </div>
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"> //content  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"> //content  </div>
</div>
```

Sorry for my English; I use Google translator.

Comment: Would you tell me how many column you want for tablets, desktops and phones?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write it! 

I would like 4 for desktop computers, 2 for tablets and 1 for phones.

Thanks for answering,

Comment: I tried to edit the CSS of bootstrap as shown in the URL that I mentioned. (I tried to edit the CSS of bootstrap as shown in the URL that I mentioned.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shall have a look at [this](http://scotch.io/bar-talk/understanding-the-bootstrap-3-grid-system) article

Basically, **[this](http://www.bootply.com/d58vQiWDws)** code should work, if I got you right:

The whole point of this grid system is that you specify what width the column should take depending on the screen size.

By default, Bootstrap got 12 columns. If you specify it like that:

`col-md-3` this means that "In the medium (below 992px and above 768px), the column should be taking 3/12 of the width, so it means there will be 4 columns.

`col-lg-6` this means that "In the large (above 992px and below 1200px), the column should be taking 6/12 of the width, so it means there will be 2 columns.

And so on, have a look at the **[Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)** reference

Comment: Thank you. It will help me a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12>
      //you content
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¡Thanks for your solution! I have the following code:


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"> //content  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"> //content  </div>
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"> //content  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"> //content  </div>
</div>

But in mobile phones show 2 columns; not 1...

Comment: use `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"> `

Comment: You should study on Bootstrap Grid system. http://getbootstrap.com/css/ @MartaFernandez

Comment: Hello @MartaFernandez accept my answer if it is helped you

Comment: @MartaFernandez  No reputations need to accept the answer, you can accept it !

Answer (score 0):

You said :

"col-md-3 this means that "In the medium (below 992px and above 768px), the column should be taking 3/12 of the width, so it means there will be 4 columns.

col-lg-6 this means that In the large (above 992px and below 1200px), the column should be taking 6/12 of the width, so it means there will be 2 columns."

I think you have made a mistake.According to w3:

Medium devices are defined as having a screen width from

> 992 pixels to 1199 pixels

and 
Large devices are defined as having a screen width from

> 1200 pixels and above

.

Comment: You are right (although you shouldn't quote w3schools. Its evil. Cite the original documentation which is the [Bootstrap doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Apart from that, this is not answer but a comment.